# Regex to extract Variable Part

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string containing this:

```
@[User::RootPath]+"Dim_MyPackage10.dtsx"
```

and I need to extract the `[User::RootPath]` part using a regex. So far I have this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.dtsx
```

but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: if  it is    @[User::myVariable]+"Dim_MyPackage10.dtsx"          I need [User::myVariable]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex pattern:

```
\[[^[\]]*\]
```

Check **[this demo](http://ideone.com/YygMmK)**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\[[^]]*\]`? The fifth character is `[` in your regex, in mine it is `]`.

Answer (score 1):

For the variable, why not consume what is needed by using the **not set** `[^ ]` to extract everything *except* in the set?

The `^` in the braces means find what is **not** matched, such as this where it seeks all that is not a `]` or a quote (`"`).

Then we can place the actual matches in named capture groups `(?<{NameHere}> )` and extract accordingly

```
string pattern = @"(?:@\[)(?<Path>[^\]]+)(?:\]\+\"")(?<File>[^\""]+)(?:"")";
// Pattern is (?:@\[)(?<Path>[^\]]+)(?:\]\+\")(?<File>[^\"]+)(?:")
// w/o the "'s escapes for the C# parser

string text = @"@[User::RootPath]+""Dim_MyPackage10.dtsx""";    

var result = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

Console.WriteLine ("Path: {0}{1}File: {2}",
    result.Groups["Path"].Value,
    Environment.NewLine,
    result.Groups["File"].Value
);

/* Outputs
Path: User::RootPath
File: Dim_MyPackage10.dtsx
*/
```

`(?: )` is match but don't capture, because we use those as defacto anchors for our pattern and to not place them into the match capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match any number of alphanumeric characters, followed by `.dtsx`. In your example, it would match `MyPackage10.dtsx`.

If you want to match `Dim_MyPackage10.dtsx` you need to add an underscore to your list of allowed characters in the regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*.dtsx`

If you want to match the `[User::RootPath]`, you need a regex that will stop at the last `/` (or `\`, depends on which type of slashes you use in the paths): something like this: `.*\/` (or `.*\\`)

Comment: Thanks, and I am really tired on the escape sequence for +

Answer (score 0):

From the answers and comments - and the fact that none has been 'accepted' so far - it appears to me that the question/problem is not completely clear. If you're looking for the pattern [User::SomeVariable] where only 'SomeVariable' is, well, variable, then you may try:

```
\[User::\w+]
```

to capture the full expression.
Furthermore, if you wish to detect that pattern, but then need only the "SomeVariable" part, you may try:

```
(?<=\[User::)\w+(?=])
```

which uses look-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is bro

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"\[\S+\]");
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```